# Update a Element's Value On An Interval

Tags: javascript, settimeout, counter

I just want a temperature counter, to show in the div "display". The default temp is 7.2, and whenever I submit another temp, it slowly decrements (0,2 per 5 minutes) to that preferred temp. Can you help me out? I am a beginner so please bear with me.
What is wrong with this code?

**JavaScript:**

```
var temp = 7.2;
var loop = setInterval(cooler, 300000);

function cooler() 
{
   document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = temp-0,2;
   setInterval(loop);
}

function abortTimer() 
{ 
   clearInterval(loop);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
   Current temp <div id="display">  </div> <br>    
    <form>
       Set temp: <input type="text" id="setTemp">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick=cooler();>
    </form>         
</body>
```

Comment: how about using `setTimeout`?

Comment: @kcdwayne Because setTimeout is only executed once. I need it executed as long as the default temp not reached the submitted temp

Answer (score 0):

There was a few things wrong with the code.

1. You decremented the value of temp but never update the variable. (temp)
2. By using setInterval you only need invoke it once. Once you clearInterval however you will need to call it again.

I changed the code a bit, updating variable names to something more appropriate. The code could definitely use some more love, but I kept my changes simple so you could follow along.

**JavaScript:**

```
var currentTemp = 7.2;
var loop = setInterval(cooler,1000);

function cooler() 
{
 currentTemp = currentTemp - 0.2;
 document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = currentTemp;
}

function setTemp()
{
  var input = document.getElementById('setTemp');
  currentTemp = parseInt(input.value);
  input.value = '';
}

function abortTimer() 
{ 
  clearInterval(loop);
}

//Wire click event to the submit button
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function()
                                                   {
                                                     setTemp();
                                                   });
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
     Current temp <div id="display">  
     </div> 
     <br>
<form>
    Set temp: <input type="text" id="setTemp">
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

See the link below for a sample of the code running at 1 second updates.
http://jsbin.com/zibuzuza/1/edit

Comment: Hi, I want the counter to change to the given input in the form. For example as I enter '3'. It then decrements 0,2. (User always has to insert lower than 7.2). I inserted a while loop like this: 
    while(currentTemp > 7.2) {
            currentTemp = currentTemp - 0.2;
        } 
but the counter doesnt respond to the submission.

Answer (score 0):

```
startChange = function(){
  var v,nt,diff,timelapse,decrease,decreaseit,loop;
  v = d.value;
  nt = t.value; 
  diff = v-nt;
  timelapse = 500; //set to whatever you like
  decrease = .2;
  decreaseit = function(){
    var v = d.value;      
    if(v>=(nt+decrease)){
     loop = setTimeout(function(){    
      d.value = (v-decrease).toFixed(1);
      decreaseit();
     },timelapse)   
    } else clearInterval(loop);
  }
  decreaseit();

}

s.onclick = startChange;
```

Using `setTimeout` to call its parent function if conditions are met, else `clearInterval`

Using `.` (numbers with decimals), you're going to run into the whole `parseFloat` problem. It's hard to work with. Not a stunning example, but the basic framework : http://jsfiddle.net/wYn6J/1/